# takeUntil with a filter

Tags: typescript, rxjs, nestjs

I have some code in NestJS with a mergeMap operator where I need to stop the observables stream based on some values from the outer and inner observables. Consider this example:

```
type SomeEvent1 {
  value: string;
}

type SomeEvent2 {
  value: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class TradeSagas {
  private readonly logger = new MyLogger(TradeSagas.name);
  @Saga()
  someSaga = (events$: Observable<IEvent>): Observable<ICommand> => {
    return events$.pipe(
      ofType(SomeEvent1),
      mergeMap((event: SomeEvent1) => {
        events$.pipe(
          ofType(SomeEvent2),
          map((event) => new SomeEvent3())
        );
      })
    );
  };
```

I need to be able to unsubscribe from the stream which listens to `SomeEvent1` or the stream which listens to `SomeEvent2`(not sure yet what is needed for my particular use case) when for example SomeEvent1.value === SomeEvent2.value.

I know I could use takeUntil operator but it accepts another observable so I am confused how I can make it work.

The reason why I want to unsubscribe is because mergeMap keeps track of all previous event values and sometimes it is messing the flow. I know I could use switchMap but that is not the solution in my particular problem since I don't need to cancel the outer observable just because the new event arrived - I have a bit more complicated logic to build the stream of events.
If there are other ideas on how to handle this problem, please, let me know.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your case, [`takeWhile`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeWhile) would be a better choice, since it takes a function rather than an observable:

```js
  someSaga = (events$: Observable<IEvent>): Observable<ICommand> => {
    return events$.pipe(
      ofType(SomeEvent1),
      mergeMap(event1 => events$.pipe(
          ofType(SomeEvent2),
          takeWhile(event2 => event2.value === event1.value),
          map(event2 => new SomeEvent3())
        );
      })
    );
  };
```

Edit:

Sometimes it's easier to follow if you break the sources up into separate variables.  So I think this might be what you are looking for:

```js
const event1$ = events$.pipe(ofType(SomeEvent1));
const event2$ = events$.pipe(ofType(SomeEvent2));
const event3$ = events$.pipe(ofType(SomeEvent3));

const someSaga2 = events1$.pipe(
  mergeMap(event1 => events2$.pipe(
    takeUntil(events3$.pipe(
        filter(event3 => event3.value === event1.value)
    ))
  ))
);
```

Description of behavior: When `Event1` emits, emit `Event2` until an `Event3` is emitted that has the same `value` as `Event1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yeah that works for the scenario I explained. Now I realized that I did a poor job of describing the use case I am having. What I wanted to do, in fact, was to cancel the flow of SomeEvent1 -> SomeEvent2 in case there is a third stream SomeEvent3 which  emits events of the same type, hence I want to stop the flow if event1.value === event3.value - otherwise proceed to merge with SomeEvent2 stream. Does that make sense?

Comment: The sample code wasn't listening to events of type `Event3`, right?  Are you saying after `event 1` is emitted, listen for `event 2` until `event 3` emits?

Comment: Yep, correct! Listen to `event 2` until `event 3` emits.

Comment: Okay, answer updated.  There's a *chance* it could work for you :-)

Comment: Awesome! I think this is it

Comment: Is it ironic that your question title is "takeUntil with a filter" and that is exactly what the solution is :-)

Comment: LMAO this is how it is with programming most of the time